Why is MySQL service shutting down every day almost at the same time?
I read the log file to see if there is anything specific that triggers shut down, but couldn't find it. It happens at 1.30AM almost every day, And then I need to manually restart MySQL. There are around 15-20 Wordpress sites on the server, if that helps.
Thank you in advance.
Here is the log file:
2024-05-01T01:30:41.338288Z 0 [Warning] option 'max_allowed_packet': unsigned value 107374182400 adjusted to 1073741824
2024-05-01T01:30:41.338960Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2024-05-01T01:30:41.338967Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER' sql mode was not set.
2024-05-01T01:30:41.338985Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2024-05-01T01:30:41.339173Z 0 [Note] /www/server/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.43-log) starting as process 1682 ...
2024-05-01T01:30:41.381140Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2024-05-01T01:30:41.381725Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2024-05-01T01:30:41.382004Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2024-05-01T01:30:41.382255Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2024-05-01T01:30:41.382536Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.13
2024-05-01T01:30:41.383351Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2024-05-01T01:30:41.384530Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2024-05-01T01:30:41.385478Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 512M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2024-05-01T01:30:41.407057Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2024-05-01T01:30:41.411577Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2024-05-01T01:30:41.427626Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2024-05-01T01:30:41.514161Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2024-05-01T01:30:41.514844Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '/www/server/data/ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2024-05-01T01:30:41.535170Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '/www/server/data/ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2024-05-01T01:30:41.535640Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2024-05-01T01:30:41.535650Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2024-05-01T01:30:41.535835Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2024-05-01T01:30:41.588161Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.43 started; log sequence number 7207964099
2024-05-01T01:30:41.588473Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /www/server/data/ib_buffer_pool
2024-05-01T01:30:41.588628Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2024-05-01T01:30:41.671776Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2024-05-01T01:30:41.671809Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2024-05-01T01:30:41.671816Z 0 [Warning] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled. Please use TLSv1.2 or higher.
2024-05-01T01:30:41.671819Z 0 [Warning] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled. Please use TLSv1.2 or higher.
2024-05-01T01:30:41.672674Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2024-05-01T01:30:41.672884Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2024-05-01T01:30:41.673258Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2024-05-01T01:30:41.673296Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2024-05-01T01:30:41.673302Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2024-05-01T01:30:41.673316Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2024-05-01T01:30:41.687478Z 0 [Note] Failed to start slave threads for channel ''
2024-05-01T01:30:41.704570Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2024-05-01T01:30:41.704838Z 0 [Note] /www/server/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.43-log'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
2024-05-01T01:30:42.905616Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 240501  1:30:42
2024-05-02T01:30:02.125746Z 0 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2024-05-02T01:30:02.125823Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2024-05-02T01:30:02.125829Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2024-05-02T01:30:02.125835Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2024-05-02T01:30:02.125884Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137649Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137713Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137716Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137720Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137722Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137744Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137747Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137754Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137757Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137759Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137761Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137763Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137765Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137784Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137787Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137789Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137791Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137793Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137794Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137796Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137798Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137800Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137802Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137804Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137806Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137808Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137810Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137812Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137814Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137816Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137818Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137820Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137822Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137824Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137826Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137828Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137830Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137832Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2024-05-02T01:30:02.137915Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2024-05-02T01:30:02.138246Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2024-05-02T01:30:02.238386Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /www/server/data/ib_buffer_pool
2024-05-02T01:30:02.240181Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 240502  1:30:02
2024-05-02T01:30:03.611798Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 7273301088
2024-05-02T01:30:03.612251Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2024-05-02T01:30:03.612268Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2024-05-02T01:30:03.612275Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2024-05-02T01:30:03.612280Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2024-05-02T01:30:03.612283Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2024-05-02T01:30:03.612406Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2024-05-02T01:30:03.616428Z 0 [Note] /www/server/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2024-05-02T01:31:39.206616Z 0 [Warning] option 'max_allowed_packet': unsigned value 107374182400 adjusted to 1073741824
2024-05-02T01:31:39.207123Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2024-05-02T01:31:39.207130Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER' sql mode was not set.
2024-05-02T01:31:39.207151Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2024-05-02T01:31:39.207322Z 0 [Note] /www/server/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.43-log) starting as process 1679 ...
2024-05-02T08:43:20.926627Z 0 [Warning] option 'max_allowed_packet': unsigned value 107374182400 adjusted to 1073741824
2024-05-02T08:43:20.926729Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2024-05-02T08:43:20.926732Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER' sql mode was not set.
2024-05-02T08:43:20.926752Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2024-05-02T08:43:20.926768Z 0 [Note] /www/server/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.43-log) starting as process 16496 ...
2024-05-02T08:43:20.950935Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2024-05-02T08:43:20.950972Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2024-05-02T08:43:20.950976Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2024-05-02T08:43:20.950979Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2024-05-02T08:43:20.950982Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.13
2024-05-02T08:43:20.951529Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2024-05-02T08:43:20.952476Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2024-05-02T08:43:20.953217Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 512M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2024-05-02T08:43:20.974122Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2024-05-02T08:43:20.978028Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2024-05-02T08:43:20.991582Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2024-05-02T08:43:21.043422Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2024-05-02T08:43:21.043487Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '/www/server/data/ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2024-05-02T08:43:21.061610Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '/www/server/data/ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2024-05-02T08:43:21.062270Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2024-05-02T08:43:21.062283Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2024-05-02T08:43:21.062712Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.43 started; log sequence number 7273301088
2024-05-02T08:43:21.062805Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /www/server/data/ib_buffer_pool
2024-05-02T08:43:21.063279Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2024-05-02T08:43:21.125910Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2024-05-02T08:43:21.125941Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2024-05-02T08:43:21.125949Z 0 [Warning] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled. Please use TLSv1.2 or higher.
2024-05-02T08:43:21.125953Z 0 [Warning] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled. Please use TLSv1.2 or higher.
2024-05-02T08:43:21.126878Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2024-05-02T08:43:21.127112Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2024-05-02T08:43:21.127485Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2024-05-02T08:43:21.127532Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2024-05-02T08:43:21.127540Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2024-05-02T08:43:21.127553Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2024-05-02T08:43:21.142230Z 0 [Note] Failed to start slave threads for channel ''
2024-05-02T08:43:21.158237Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2024-05-02T08:43:21.158525Z 0 [Note] /www/server/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.43-log'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
2024-05-02T08:43:22.259790Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 240502  8:43:22


Welcome to Server Fault! Please format console output / settings / commands /logs    as "code" using Markdown and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts. That retains formatting, indentation and avoids Markdown mishaps,  as well as improves readability and attracts better answers.

An external command,  like logrotate, might be issuing a restart and failing. If something like that happens daily at more or less the same time, that and cron are the first things to investigate

What time are backups taken?

You could use CRON to TURN ON your General Log at 1:28 AM to find out what is trying to run.  AND also to protect against filling your storage media, use CRON to TURN OFF your General Log at 1:32 AM.  When things are stabilized, remove BOTH from your CRON activities.

Consider changing your my.ini or my.cnf in [mysqld] section
max_allowed_packet=1073741824  # because this is the MAX allowed ( 1 GB )

stop/start the instance and the Warning should NOT be listed any longer in your error.log.
